# meaning of vi command :s/1,$/ABC/CBS?

Tags: linux, unix

does anybody know what this vi command means?

am very new with Linux   and i was asked to explain what it does but am getting an error message

any idea what it means or why am i getting this error?

```
:s/1,$/ABC/CBS
```

error message

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `:s/1,$/ABC/CBS` means, *replace the `1,` at the end of line by `ABC` with unknown modifier `CBS`*. Due to this *unknown modifier* its a **wrong command**

If it would have been like `:1,$ s/ABC/CBS/`, It would mean, *replace the first `ABC` with `CBS` for each line starting from line `1` to the last line (`$`) of the file*

Comment: thank you, yeah, it seems like my professor has a typo with this assignment, thanks a lot! you just make my day!

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be:

```
:1,$s/ABC/CBS
```

i.e. replace the first occurrence of ABC by CBS on every line in the file.

Comment: everywhere is not quite true; in every line, but only the first occurrence. else, the /g modifier would be necessary. and the trailing slash is missing.

Comment: Nope. it wont replace every `ABC`s with `CBS`. It'll replace **only the first** one.

Comment: Indeed, my point was more about the typo than the precise meaning but answer corrected. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

this is a command to replace 'aa' with 'bb':

```
:s/aa/bb/
```

your code actually tries to replace '1,' at the end of the line with 'ABC'

the error you get means that 'CBS' is not a valid trailing flag. Flags I use are:

```
g for global
c for ask confirmation
I for ignore case
```

for more info, please check [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)